# How to send an ArrayList in the body of an e-mail in android?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I want to send in the body of the e-mail an ArrayList with some values.
Like this:

```
Button bt_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_cadastrar_medicos);
        bt_cadastrar_medicos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                intent.setType("plain/text");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "email@email");  
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT"); 
                ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();                  
                for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                                    String ii = String.valueOf(i);
                    niveis.add(ii);             
                        niveis.add(ii);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, niveis.get(i));
                }

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose the app to send:"));
            }
        });
```

This is just an example, actually I want to add in which array position values that a get from a java class. But in the body just the last value appears, in this case would be the "2".

How do I show all of them in the body? Is that possible?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for-loop, this call

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, niveis.get(i));
```

is replacing the EXTRA_TEXT data on each pass through the loop. You need to build the entire string that you want to send as the EXTRA_TEXT, then add that to the intent via a single call to putExtra(). E.g.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
for (String s : myArrayList) {
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append("\n");
}
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sb.toString());
```

Comment: Wow, just was missing in my code the "to string" in my Arraylist. And using you're code works too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    niveis.add("1");                
    niveis.add("2");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, niveis.get(i));
}
```

On first iteration of the `for` loop:

```
niveis looks like
    1 , 2

Intent.EXTRA_TEXT is the key to: niveis.get(0) ==>> 1
```

On second iteration of the `for` loop:

```
niveis looks like
    1 , 2 , 1 , 2

Intent.EXTRA_TEXT is the key to: niveis.get(1) ==>> 2
```

Not sure what you are trying to do. But, the the reason for

> But in the body just the last value appears, in this case would be the
>   "2"

is explained above.

Comment: I have a database and my ideia is to call the datas and add in the "niveis" array, so on click button the email will be send and all the datas will show in the body. How can I do that? Note: this "1", "2" are just examples, actually, in which position I do like this: String values = javaClass.Method().get(i).getTag();
niveis.add(values);